# Where to find the song that is basically "next to you" played with a different instrument?

Tags: music, parasyte

In Episode 8 at 10:40, when Shinichi throws the dog in the trash, a song plays that I have not been able to find anywhere on the internet.

I know the song is basically "*next to you*" with a different instrument playing it, but I want to know where I can find the whole song played with that specific sound.

The original "*next to you*" OST just does not give the same sad feeling as this other song.

Comment: Have you tried [*this* anime version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvCPNy3USaU) of the tune yet? It's the softest tune I could find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the tune you are looking for is [Next to You-Anime Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvCPNy3USaU). This one is different from the [Original One](https://youtu.be/DVl9XNs8jqw) in the aspects of being slower and softer, and with a totally different instrument playing it and from the other [Anime Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RRQjhlSUIg) in the same terms.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find it in any of the OSTs. It might be an unreleased track for an unreleased OST, but that's anyone's guess.